# Why is formatting a disk faster in the CMD shell than in Windows Explorer?

Tags: formatting

Why does formatting the disk in Windows take 10 minutes, but when I type "format c:\" in CMD it only takes several seconds?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is because you can ask to fill the disk with zeros (full-format) which has to write all blocks of the partition or just rewrite new meta info on disk, without wiping all data, which is quick-format and only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Long format does not write zeros to the drive, a common misconception,  it deletes any data on the disk by deleting/recreating the partition, then scans the drive for bad sectors...http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;302686&Product=winxp